# Make the image in 2017 Developer Survey result clickable/zoom-able

Tags: support, feature-request, images, survey-2017

Some sections have images embedded:

- [Developer Role and Gender](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/#developer-profile-developer-role-and-gender)
- [Languages Over Time](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/#technology-languages-over-time)
- [Correlated Technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/#technology-correlated-technologies)

On my Chrome browser with 100% zoom, the image's text is comparatively smaller than the body text, making it a bit hard to be read, e.g.:

> [image: Languages Over Time]

I still managed to understand it since it's clear enough. However, this particular image:

> [image: Correlated Technologies]

I was having a hard time to read those tiny text.

When I opened the image in a new tab, I noticed that it's actually a vector image (`.svg`). Now, *considering that the images are actually vector image*, is it possible to make it clickable/zoom-able to for more convenience?